# iOS 8 tableview cell constraints broken

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios8

I'm not sure what Apple changed in iOS 8 but my tableview cells constraints are now broken.

They were working perfectly fine in iOS 7, the cells appeared and behaved exactly as I intended them to, no constraint conflicts log message from Xcode.

But after upgrading my phone to iOS 8 and running my app, I got constraint conflict Xcode log messages.

I haven't changed my code or anything. Could it be something related to iOS 8 new layoutMargins property?

Is anyone else having the same problem?

Hopefully I'm not not duplicating existing questions, please close if so.

### Some Clarification

My app doesn't use Interface Builder, everything is done by code.

As I said, I haven't changed the layout code for my cells, they work perfect normal on an iPhone 5 running iOS 7 but as soon as I run the app on the iOS 8 iPhone 5, the same code shows constraint conflicts all of a sudden:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14f735b0 V:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x14f6bb60]   (Names: '|':NotificationsiPhoneTableViewCell:0x14f6a690'cellID' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14f73610 V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x14f6bb60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NotificationsiPhoneTableViewCell:0x14f6a690'cellID' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14f72b80 UserPhotoView:0x14f6c170.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x14f6bb60.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14f72be0 V:[UserPhotoView:0x14f6c170(37.5)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14f72c20 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14f6bb60.bottomMargin == UserPhotoView:0x14f6c170.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14de0260 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[NotificationsiPhoneTableViewCell:0x14f6a690'cellID'(76)]>"
)
```

I repeat, I do not get these constraint conflict error messages when I run it on iOS 7 device.

I didn't just started learning Autolayout today, I've been using it for a few months now and know about some of the pitfalls and problems to avoid with Autolayout. I'm inclined to believe this isn't a beginner mistake.

### Update

OK, I concede. I did in fact made some mistakes in my autolayout constraint code.

I'm a terrible liar.

I looked through my constraints code and fixed them all for the notifications page.

This notifications page is the easy one, now I got to fix the other crazy one that got a complex layout >.<

Seems like iOS 8 is more better a picking up conflicting constraints. *thumbs up*

I just hope I can fix that other page.

Comment: Can you post some more information on what error you're getting?

Comment: Post images of your cell / constraints + check if the constraints are all blue. Also add a copy of the log message. The constraint conflict messages would seem to imply that at least one constraint is orange / red in IB.